# Android HTTPUrlConnection : how to set post data in http body?

Tags: android, httpurlconnection, postdata

I've already created my HTTPUrlConnection :

```
String postData = "x=val1&y=val2";
URL url = new URL(strURL);
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
conn.setRequestProperty("Set-Cookie", sessionCookie);
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" + Integer.toString(postData.getBytes().length));

// How to add postData as http body?

conn.setUseCaches(false);
conn.setDoInput(true);
conn.setDoOutput(true);
```

I don't know how to set postData in http body. How to do so? Would I better use `HttpPost` instead?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you want to send Json data?

Comment: @MaximShoustin Can't I simply send it as a String ? I usually do this in iOS : `NSString *string = @"x=val1&y=val2"; NSData *postData = [string dataUsingEncoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:NO]; [request setHTTPBody:postData];`

Answer (score 86, accepted):

If you want to send String only try this way:

```
String str =  "some string goes here";
byte[] outputInBytes = str.getBytes("UTF-8");
OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
os.write( outputInBytes );    
os.close();
```

But if you want to send as Json change Content type to:

```
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/json");
```

and now our `str` we can write:

```
String str =  "{\"x\": \"val1\",\"y\":\"val2\"}";
```

Hope it will help,

Comment: It's not valid JSON to use simple quotes in key names. :p

Comment: @JulienPalard tnx, fixed

Comment: Complete example here :) 
http://guruparang.blogspot.com/2016/01/example-on-working-with-json-and.html

Answer (score 4):

[Guruparan's link](http://guruparang.blogspot.com/2016/01/example-on-working-with-json-and.html) in the comment above gives a really nice answer to this question. I highly recommend looking at it. Here is the principle that makes his solution work:

From what I understand, the HttpURLConnection represents the response body as an OutputStream. So you need to call something like:

get the connection's output stream

```
OutputStream op = conn.getOuputStream();
```

write the response body

```
op.write( [/*your string in bit form*/] );
```

close the output stream

```
op.close();
```

and then carry on your merry way with the connection (which you will still need to close).